# Handle mongoose errors with ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using ExpressJS framework and mongoose libary .

When I write down my routes, I want to handle exceptions on db errors. but my code dont handling it correct. 
I read about it around internet, but still have no idea .

router :

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    Cars.find({}, (err, all) => {
        if (err) {
              console.log("error ! ");
              return next(err);
        }
        res.send(all);
    })
});
```

middleware error handler :

```
app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
console.log("I got exception")
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error',{
    message: err.message,
    error:err
});
```

To test that issue , I've tried to stopp the mongoDB service.instead of getting exception the response not loading .

How can I handle this correctly ?
Thanks